# Java regex validating special chars

Tags: java, regex, validation

This seems like a well known title, but I am really facing a problem in this.

Here is what I have and what I've done so far.

I have validate input string, these chars are not allowed :

> &%$##@!~

So I coded it like this:

```
 String REGEX = "^[&%$##@!~]";
 String username= "jhgjhgjh.#";
 Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(REGEX);
 Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(username);
 if (matcher.matches()) {
     System.out.println("matched");
 }
```

Comment: Is there a reason you doubled the `##` inside the character class? - Only one is necessary, unless you want to allow `##` but not `#` - which would require a different expression.

Comment: I guess it's a spelling mistake :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change your first line of code like this

```
String REGEX = "[^&%$#@!~]*";
```

And it should work fine. `^` outside the  character class denotes start of line. `^` inside a character class `[]` means a negation of the characters inside the character class. And, if you don't want to match empty usernames, then use this regex

```
String REGEX = "[^&%$#@!~]+";
```

Comment: based on the question, it looks as though empty string should be matched, so the + should be a *

Comment: Thanks, changed it. Added a note about non-empty usernames as well just to make it clear.

Answer (score 2):

i think you want this:

```
[^&%$##@!~]*
```

Answer (score 2):

To match a valid input:

```
String REGEX = "[^&%$#@!~]*";
```

To match an invalid input:

```
String REGEX = ".*[&%$#@!~]+.*";
```